# Proving Radius of Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I am working on a problem and I am to prove that:

$$\frac {\pi}{4}=1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\cdots$$

and I am given the hint: $(−1)^n x^{2n} = \frac {1}{1+x^2}$ for all $|x| < 1$.

If $\sum (−1)^{n}x^{2n} = \frac {1}{1+x^{2}}$ for all $|x| < 1,$ then $\sum \frac {(-1)^n}{n+1}x^{2(n+1)} = \int_0^x$ $\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}$ for all $|x| < 1$ by thm.

Now, when I integrate I get $\arctan(x)$ whose limit is $\frac {\pi}{2}$ which is wrong. I would really appreciate some help, thanks.

Comment: Don't integrate $0$ to $\infty$, integrate $0$ to $1$.

Comment: I integrated from 0 to $\inf$ because of the equivalence to the sum. Why is this not ok?

Comment: The limit going to $\infty$ is for $n$, not $x$. You wrote yourself that your formula is only valid for $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\arctan 1 = \frac\pi4.{{{{{{{{{{{{}}}}}}}}}}}}
$$